# Visualization API - Issue with centering chart

Tags: google-visualization

Using the [Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/), I am drawing a very simple `ColumnChart`, with no legend.

I don't know why, but the chart is not centered in its container, as if the space for the legend on the right was kept, although the legend is not displayed.

But if I change the legend position to bottom, for example, that space is still present. So I am not sure if this is related to the legend.

Please check my <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/xyqF7/)</kbd>. Notice the big padding on the right (around 55px).

Any way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you're right about that. If you check DOM elements, for example values, you can see that position is the same if legend position is `none` or `right`: `<g><text text-anchor="end" x="46" y="44" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="10" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0072c6">11.000</text></g>`. (x,y) position is the same in both cases. You expect centered chart and in that case x value has to change, at least.

Comment: Right. But looking at [the examples](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Colors) it seems correct (?).

Comment: It is correct. It seems that it is design in that way if there is no legend on the right that space is "booked". If you put vAxis on the right it will be placed right there. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyqF7/7/).

Comment: Yes, and set the legend position to none, and now the padding is on the left! I think I'll submit an issue to Google. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chartArea *is* centered in the chart (the axis labels are not considered part of the chartArea, it is easier to see that it is centered if you turn them off: http://jsfiddle.net/xyqF7/9/), what you want to do is move it off-center, which you can do via the `chartArea` options:

```
chartArea: {
    width: '80%',
    left: '15%'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyqF7/8/

Comment: I didn't know about that `chartArea` object. Good point! That is exactly what I was expecting.